# Different result when put outside of event listener?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Sorry I am bad at asking questions, if you don't understand what I am asking please let me know

```
let node = this.createSvgNode("rect", {
    'data-id': section.id || '',
    x: section.x,
    y: section.y,
    width: section.width,
    height: section.height,
    fill: section.backgroundColor || "#EEEEEE"
});

let thisObject = this; 

let paths = thisObject.findPaths(7, 3)  // Doesn't work

node.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    let paths = thisObject.findPaths(7, 3)  // works
});
```

I don't understand why `let paths = thisObject.findPaths(7, 3)` works when it is inside the event listener and doesn't when it is outside of the event listener. isn't it the same?

btw this is the findPaths function:

```
findPaths: function (startId, endId) {
let paths = [];
let startDoors = doors[startId];
let endDoors   = doors[endId];
    
for (let i = 0; i < startDoors.length; i++) {
    let startingPoint = this.findPointByCoordinates(startDoors[i]);
    // console.log("Starting Point: " + JSON.stringify(startingPoint));

    for (let j = 0; j < doors[endId].length; j++) {
        let endingPoint = this.findPointByCoordinates(endDoors[j]);
        // console.log("Ending Point: " + JSON.stringify(endingPoint));

        let potentialPath = this.recursiveIterationOfPoints([startingPoint], endingPoint);

        // console.log(potentialPath);

        paths = paths.concat(potentialPath);
    }
}

for (let id in paths) {
    paths[id] = this.linkRoomsWithPath(paths[id], startId, endId);
}

return paths;
},
```

I get this error when I put `let paths = thisObject.findPaths(7, 3)` above the event listener:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

here is the full code

```
(function (global) {
var IndoorMaps = function (options) {
    return new IndoorMaps.init(options);
};

let svgRootNode;
let doors = {};
let hallwayPoints = {};

let currentZIndex = 0;
let validZIndexes = [0];
let showHallwayPoints = false;

//let svgDimensions = {};

let floorPlan = [];

let mapSelection = null;

IndoorMaps.init = function (options) {
    this.parseConfiguration(options || {});
    this.parseFloorPlan(options.floorSections || {});
    this.parseHallwayPoints(options.hallway || {});

    //svgDimensions = this.calculateSVGWidthAndHeight();

    svgRootNode = this.createSvgNode("svg", {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
    });

    this.appendToBody(svgRootNode);

    // Render the Map
    this.drawMap(floorPlan[currentZIndex] || {});

    if (showHallwayPoints) {
        this.displayHallwayPoints(options.hallway || {});
    }

    return svgRootNode;
};

IndoorMaps.init.prototype = {
    createSvgNode: function (elementName, attributes = {}, value) {
        if (elementName === undefined) {
            throw "Element name not found!";
        }

        let node = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", elementName);

        for (let attributeKey in attributes) {
            node.setAttribute(attributeKey, attributes[attributeKey]);
        }

        if (value !== undefined) {
            node.innerHTML = value;
        }

        return node;
    },
    appendToBody: function (node) {
        window.document.body.appendChild(node);
    },
    draw: function (node) {
        let panZoom = svgRootNode.querySelector('.svg-pan-zoom_viewport');

        if (!panZoom) {
            svgRootNode.append(node);
        } else {
            panZoom.append(node);
        }
    },
    addDoors: function(roomId, doorPoints) {
        doors[roomId] = doorPoints;

        for (let i = 0; i < doorPoints.length; i++) {
            let coordinates = doorPoints[i];

            let attributes = {
                x: coordinates.x,
                y: coordinates.y,
                width: coordinates.width || 0,
                height: coordinates.height || 0,
                fill: "#FF0000"
            };

            if (coordinates.width > coordinates.height) {
                attributes.x -= coordinates.width / 2;
                attributes.y -= coordinates.height;
            }

            if (coordinates.height > coordinates.width) {
                attributes.x -= coordinates.width;
                attributes.y -= coordinates.height / 2;
            }

            let rect = this.createSvgNode("rect", attributes);

            this.draw(rect);
        }
    },
    drawMap: function (floorSections) {
        for (let i = 0; i < floorSections.length; i++) {
            let section = floorSections[i];

            if (
                section.x === undefined
                || section.y === undefined
                || section.width === undefined
                || section.height === undefined
            ) {
                throw "The x,y coordinates and the width and height are required fields.";
            }

            let node = this.createSvgNode("rect", {
                'data-id': section.id || '',
                x: section.x,
                y: section.y,
                width: section.width,
                height: section.height,
                fill: section.backgroundColor || "#EEEEEE"
            });

            let thisObject = this;

            node.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                if (mapSelection === null) {
                    thisObject.removeRouteIndicators();
                    mapSelection = this;
                    this.classList.add('selected');
                } else {
                    console.log(mapSelection.dataset.id + " : " + this.dataset.id);
                    let paths = thisObject.findPaths(mapSelection.dataset.id, this.dataset.id);

                    let shortestPath = thisObject.findShortestPath(paths);

                    thisObject.drawPath(shortestPath);

                    mapSelection = null;
                    this.classList.add('destination');
                }
            });

            this.draw(node);
            this.addDoors(section.id, section.doors);

            if (section.label === undefined) {
                continue;
            }

            if (section.label.text === undefined) {
                throw "The text must be included for the label to be shown. Set label as null if you do not wish to display a label.";
            }

            xCoordinate = section.x + (section.label.x || 0);
            yCoordinate = section.y + (section.label.y || 0);

            let attributes = {
                'x': xCoordinate,
                'y': yCoordinate,
                'fill': section.label.color || '#333333',
                'font-family': section.label.fontStyle || 'Verdana',
                'font-size': section.label.fontSize || '10'
            };

            if (section.label.alignment === undefined) {
                section.label.alignment = "center|center";
            }

            if (section.label.alignment !== undefined) {
                switch (section.label.alignment) {
                    case "center|center":
                        attributes['text-anchor'] = "middle";
                        attributes['dominant-baseline'] = "middle";
                        attributes['x'] = (section.width / 2) + section.x;
                        attributes['y'] = (section.height / 2) + section.y;
                        break;
                    case "horizontal_center":
                        attributes['text-anchor'] = "middle";
                        attributes['x'] = (section.width / 2) + section.x;
                        break;
                    case "vertical_center":
                        attributes['dominant-baseline'] = "middle";
                        attributes['y'] = (section.height / 2) + section.y;
                        break;
                    default:
                        throw "Alignment mode requested was not found.";
                }
            }

            let textNode = this.createSvgNode("text", attributes, section.label.text);

            this.draw(textNode);
        }
    },

    drawPath: function(path) {
        for (let i = 0; i < (path.length - 1); i++) {
            let lineNode = this.createSvgNode('line', {
                x1: path[i].x,
                y1: path[i].y,
                x2: path[i + 1].x,
                y2: path[i + 1].y,
                stroke: "green",
                'data-type': "route"
            });

            this.draw(lineNode);
        }
    },

    removeRouteIndicators: function () {
        let nodes = svgRootNode.querySelectorAll('[data-type="route"]');
        let panZoom = svgRootNode.querySelector('.svg-pan-zoom_viewport');

        for (let index = 0; index < nodes.length; index++) {
            if (!panZoom) {
                svgRootNode.removeChild(nodes[index]);
            } else {
                panZoom.removeChild(nodes[index]);
            }
        }

        nodes = svgRootNode.getElementsByClassName('selected');

        for (let index = 0; index < nodes.length; index++) {
            nodes[index].classList.remove('selected');
        }

        nodes = svgRootNode.getElementsByClassName('destination');

        for (let index = 0; index < nodes.length; index++) {
            nodes[index].classList.remove('destination');
        }
    },

    displayHallwayPoints: function (hallwayNodes) {
        for (let i = 0; i < hallwayNodes.length; i++) {
            this.draw(
                this.createSvgNode("circle", {
                    cx: hallwayNodes[i].x,
                    cy: hallwayNodes[i].y,
                    r: 2,
                    fill: hallwayNodes[i].fill || "black",
                    'data-id': hallwayNodes[i].id
                })
            );
        }
    },
    findPaths: function (startId, endId) {
        let paths = [];
        let startDoors = doors[startId];
        let endDoors   = doors[endId];

        for (let i = 0; i < startDoors.length; i++) {
            let startingPoint = this.findPointByCoordinates(startDoors[i]);
            console.log("Starting Point: " + JSON.stringify(startingPoint));

            for (let j = 0; j < doors[endId].length; j++) {
                let endingPoint = this.findPointByCoordinates(endDoors[j]);
                console.log("Ending Point: " + JSON.stringify(endingPoint));

                let potentialPath = this.recursiveIterationOfPoints([startingPoint], endingPoint);

                console.log(potentialPath);

                paths = paths.concat(potentialPath);
            }
        }

        for (let id in paths) {
            paths[id] = this.linkRoomsWithPath(paths[id], startId, endId);
        }

        return paths;
    },
    recursiveIterationOfPoints: function(path, end) {
        let results = [];
        let current = path[path.length - 1];

        console.log(current);

        if (current.id === end.id) {
            return [path];
        }

        for (let i = 0; i < current.connected.length; i++) {
            let nextPoint = hallwayPoints[current.connected[i]];

            let found = false;

            path.forEach( function (point, index) {
                if (point.id === nextPoint.id) {
                    found = true;
                }
            });

            if (found)
                continue;

            var newPath = path.slice();
            newPath.push(nextPoint);

            results = results.concat(this.recursiveIterationOfPoints(newPath, end));
        }

        return results;
    },
    findPointByCoordinates: function (coordinates) {
        for (let id in hallwayPoints) {
            let point = hallwayPoints[id];

            if (point.x === coordinates.x && point.y === coordinates.y) {
                return point;
            }
        }
    },
    findActualCoordinatesOfDoorByCoordinates: function (coordinates, roomId) {
        let validDoors = doors[roomId];

        for (let id in validDoors) {
            if (validDoors[id].x === coordinates.x && validDoors[id].y === coordinates.y) {
                return validDoors[id].actual;
            }
        }
    },
    parseHallwayPoints: function (points) {
        for (let i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
            hallwayPoints[points[i].id] = points[i];
        }
    },
    findShortestPath: function(paths) {
        if (paths.length === 1)
            return paths[0];

        // Set benchmark range
        let shortestDistance = this.calculateDistanceForPath(paths[0]);
        let shortestPath = paths[0];

        // Skip the first since it's already calculated.
        for (let i = 1; i < paths.length; i++) {
            let distance = this.calculateDistanceForPath(paths[i]);

            if (distance < shortestDistance) {

                shortestDistance = distance;
                shortestPath = paths[i];
            }
        }

        return shortestPath;
    },
    calculateDistanceForPath: function(path) {
        let totalDistance = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < (path.length - 1); i++) {
            // Formula: sqrt[(x0 - x1)^2 + (y0 - y1)^2]
            totalDistance += Math.sqrt(Math.pow(path[i].x - path[i + 1].x, 2) + Math.pow(path[i].y - path[i + 1].y, 2));
        }

        return totalDistance;
    },
    linkRoomsWithPath: function (path, startId, endId) {
        let first = this.findActualCoordinatesOfDoorByCoordinates(path[0], startId);
        let last  = this.findActualCoordinatesOfDoorByCoordinates(path[path.length - 1], endId);

        path.unshift(first);
        path.push(last);

        return path;
    },

    parseConfiguration: function (options) {
        currentZIndex = options.config.defaultZIndex || 0;
        validZIndexes = options.config.validZIndexes || [0];
        showHallwayPoints = options.config.showHallwayPoints || false;
    },

    parseFloorPlan: function (floorLayout) {
        for (let i in floorLayout) {
            if (floorLayout[i].z === undefined) {
                floorLayout[i].z = 0;
            }

            if (!(floorLayout[i].z in floorPlan)) {
                floorPlan[floorLayout[i].z] = [];
            }

            floorPlan[floorLayout[i].z].push(floorLayout[i]);
        }
    },

    calculateSVGWidthAndHeight: function () {
        let dimensions = {
            width: 0,
            height: 0
        };

        let floorLayout = floorPlan[currentZIndex];
        let first = true;

        for (let i in floorLayout) {
            let calculatedWidth  = floorLayout[i].width + floorLayout[i].x;
            let calculatedHeight = floorLayout[i].height + floorLayout[i].y;

            if (first) {
                 dimensions.width = calculatedWidth;
                 dimensions.height = calculatedHeight;

                 first = false;
            }

            if (calculatedWidth > dimensions.width) {

                dimensions.width = calculatedWidth;
            }


            if (calculatedHeight > dimensions.height) {
                dimensions.height = calculatedHeight;
            }
        }

        for (let i in hallwayPoints) {
            let currentWidth = hallwayPoints[i].x;
            let currentHeight = hallwayPoints[i].y;

            if (currentWidth > dimensions.width) {
                dimensions.width = currentWidth;
            }

            if (currentHeight > dimensions.height) {
                dimensions.height = currentHeight;
            }

        }

        return dimensions;
    }
};

window.indoorMaps = IndoorMaps;
```

}(window));

Comment: The `this` context is different when called outside vs inside the event handler callback.

Comment: ohh, but do you know how can I make it so that I can use `thisObject.findPaths(7, 3)` outside of the event listener ?

Comment: @Terry I don't think that's what's going on here. It seems that either `doors[startId]`, `doors[endId]`, or both are undefined.

Comment: _It seems_ that `doors` exists, but is empty when you call `.findPaths()`, though it is not when the event is triggered. Make sure that `doors` is filled before try to use it.

Comment: I made an update and included the full code

Comment: Are you calling it before the element is on the page? Use console.log() to see what is different in your findPaths method.

Comment: @kosmos, thank you very much it is because of the door. If you want you can create an answer and I can accept the answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm glad that you solved it 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment above, it seems that at the point you are calling `findPaths()`, `doors` exists, but is empty when you call `findPaths()`, though it is not when the event is triggered. Make sure that `doors` is filled before try to use it.